# Link between points and triangles

Tags: c++

I want to make a link between 2 classes and im not sure what is the best aproach for it. What i have is a set of points where i use delaunay triangulation to find triangles between them (note that a point can belong to several triangles). Next, the positions of these points are tracked and updated throughout several frames of a video. Therefore, the position of the triangles also need to be updated somehow. Next to that, i would also like to be able to remove a point which gets lost and automatically remove the triangles associated with it. Could you guys give me some advice how to combine these classes?

```
class Point  
{ 
  float x,y;
}

class Triangle
{
  Point p1, pt2, pt3;
}
```

Comment: Combine? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Hi,  thank you for the reaction. The Point objects need to know which triangles are associated with them (in order to delete them if needed) and the triangles should point to 3 Points (in order to get the current position). Now my only idea is to work "ofcourse" with pointers but i was hoping there is an elegant way to keep track of everything.

Comment: Do you need a free function that takes a container of points and is called each time points change, returning a new container of the triangles?

Comment: I hope i understand your question right: The triangles should be kept between the same points at all times. So there is a step that initializes the triangles and then these triangles are tracked.

Comment: Are you sure that "these triangles" are tracked? I believe instead you have an images sequence. You initialize your tracker by detecting some feature points (2D) in the first frame. Then, with Delaunay, you trianglulate you point cloud which gives you a 2D mesh. Then, you only need to update your 2D points cloud by tracking your image features over time. Is this right? If yes, then, do you need to update your 2D points at each frame or only "once in a while"?

Comment: This is exactly what i want to do. Im sorry if this was not clear. The points need to be updated each frame. And per frame i want to compute statistics for the triangles, for example the avg rgb values.

Comment: So you need to store points trajectories, not just points. If you track at each frame, then you can store the points as a 2D array. If you have a non-uniform sampling, then you need to store keyframes and then interpolate to find inbetween values. Finally, you can update the initial triangles at subsequent frames by setting a boolean value (like valid). For example, a triangle is valid by default, and invalid if it has at least 1 "missing point".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such collections interaction in computer graphics typically be implemented using indices.

```
class Point
{ 
  float x,y;
}

class Triangle
{
  unsigned int indices[3]; // indices in std::vector<Points>
}

std::vector<Points> points;
std::vector<Triangle> triangles;
```

Main advantage, comparing with pointers solution is that you can use such index referencing in shader programs.

**edit:**
Code example to remove vertex by known index (not tested). Note that now we store vertices in std::map, to not break indexing when erasing indices.

```
class Mesh
{
public:
    struct Vertex
    {
        float x, y;
    };

    struct Triangle
    {
        bool Contains(unsigned int index) const 
        { 
            return ((indices[0] == index) || (indices[1] == index) || (indices[2] == index));
        }

        unsigned int indices[3];
    };

    // Removes vertex and corresponding triangles
    void RemoveByIndex(unsigned int index)
    {
        for (auto it = triangles.begin(); it != triangles.end(); ++it)
        {
            if (it->Contains(index))
                triangles.erase(it);
        }

        vertices.erase(index);
    }

private:
    std::map<unsigned int, Vertex> vertices;
    std::vector<Triangle> triangles;
};
```

Of course, there are much space for optimizations: first is a types of containers, but it depends on size of collection, and how often you inserting/erasing data.

Comment: Can you also suggest me a clean method for removing a point and corresponding triangles? Thanks

Comment: @Drop: curious - why not store an array of `Point` inside triangle instead of the indices?

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo, in this case (store points by value), if one vertex contained by multiple triangles, you will store redundant copies of same vertex. If vertex consists only of 2D position is OK, but you still must change points in all triangles when you changing vertex position. And if vertex stores also normals, color, texture coords etcю it is also a substantial memory impact.

Comment: @Drop, thanks for the code. The map container was unknown for me! I think this approach is good as a starting points.

Answer (score 1):

@slava is referring to the fact that you said a point can belong to several triangles.  With that in mind your classes should look something like:

```
class Point  
{ 
  float x,y;
}

class Triangle
{
  Point * p1;
  Point * pt2;
  Point * pt3;
}
```

The way you've defined your Triangle class, you would have been carrying around copies of the points.  If the points had been modified, your Triangle class would have had to be updated separately.

Keeping in mind that these aren't literal class definitions (everything's private) and that you'll probably want to use a reference counted pointer like unique_ptr

Comment: I think many points may be inside a triangle, but a triangle is defined by three points, what with it being a triangle and all. Those three points may not be the points that we are trying to triangulate

Comment: Thanks for the comment, So pointers are the way to go here? How could i make the Point aware of which triangles are "following" him so i could easily remove the triangles if the Point gets removed?

Comment: The triangles only contain 3 points which are the corner points. These points, however, can also be corner points of other triangles. (How many is not known in advance)

Comment: Now you're getting to the larger problem.  Think about the way that the data structures will be used in the full context of the program.  Not just as clouds of points and triangles (perhaps strips as well or other structures).  You're working with a visual problem, draw out the typical structure of your data and the class structure will likely follow.
Once you've done that, think about the operations that will be performed on those structures and make sure that you've got the right links between the structures that the operations can be made efficient.

Comment: Read the last line of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use the following data structures:

```
struct Point
{
    double x, y;
};

struct Triangle
{
    unsigned int ids[3];
    bool isValid;
};

// Store points for each frame
std::vector<std::vector<Point>> points;
// Store triangles
std::vector<Triangle> triangles;
```

You could also keep ALL triangle for each frame like so:

```
// Store triangles for each frame
std::vector<std::vector<Triangle>> triangles;
```

And here is a "working example". 4 points, 2 triangles during 3 frames. It outputs only triangles whose vertices are ALL positive. From one frame to the other, the point cloud is translated by -1 along Y axis. It is obviously a fake test but it will hopefully help you start.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Point
{
    double x, y;
};

struct Triangle
{
    unsigned int ids[3];
    bool isValid;
};

void TrackFirstFrame(std::vector<Point> &firstFrame)
{
    Point p1, p2, p3, p4;
    p1.x = 1; p1.y = 0;
    p2.x = 2; p2.y = 1;
    p3.x = 1; p3.y = 2;
    p4.x = 0; p4.y = 1;
    firstFrame[0] = p1;
    firstFrame[1] = p2;
    firstFrame[2] = p3;
    firstFrame[3] = p4;
}

void Delaunay(const std::vector<Point> &points, std::vector<Triangle> &triangles)
{
    Triangle t1;
    t1.ids[0] = 0;
    t1.ids[1] = 1;
    t1.ids[2] = 3;
    triangles.push_back(t1);

    Triangle t2;
    t2.ids[0] = 1;
    t2.ids[1] = 2;
    t2.ids[2] = 3;
    triangles.push_back(t2);
}

// Assumption: all previous frame points give a new tracked point for current frame 
void TrackFrame(const std::vector<Point> &previousFramePoints, unsigned int currentFrame, std::vector<Point> &trackedPoints)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < previousFramePoints.size(); ++i)
    {
        Point previousPoint = previousFramePoints[i];
        Point trackedPoint;
        trackedPoint.x = previousPoint.x;
        trackedPoint.y = previousPoint.y - 1;
        trackedPoints[i] = trackedPoint;
    }
}

// Assumption: all vertices are positive. If not, triangle is invalid
void UpdateTriangles(const std::vector<Point> &points, std::vector<Triangle> &triangles)
{
    std::vector<Triangle>::iterator trianglesIT = triangles.begin();
    for (; trianglesIT != triangles.end(); ++trianglesIT)
    {
        (*trianglesIT).isValid = true; // By default
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            Point vertex = points[(*trianglesIT).ids[i]];
            if (vertex.x < 0 || vertex.y < 0)
            {
                (*trianglesIT).isValid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void PrintPoints(const std::vector<Point> &points)
{
    std::cout<<"Points"<<std::endl;
    std::vector<Point>::const_iterator pointsIT = points.begin();
    for (; pointsIT != points.end(); ++pointsIT)
    {
        std::cout<<"("<<pointsIT->x<<", "<<pointsIT->y<<")"<<std::endl;
    }
}

void PrintTriangles(const std::vector<Triangle> &triangles)
{
    std::cout<<"Triangles"<<std::endl;
    std::vector<Triangle>::const_iterator trianglesIT = triangles.begin();
    for (; trianglesIT != triangles.end(); ++trianglesIT)
    {
        if (trianglesIT->isValid)
        {
            std::cout<<"["<<trianglesIT->ids[0]<<", "<<trianglesIT->ids[1]<<", "<<trianglesIT->ids[2]<<"])"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int nbFrames = 3;
    unsigned int nbPoints = 4;

    // Init 2D points
    std::vector<std::vector<Point>> points;
    points.resize(nbFrames);
    std::vector< std::vector<Point> >::iterator framesIT = points.begin();
    for (; framesIT != points.end(); ++framesIT)
    {
        framesIT->resize(nbPoints);
    }

    TrackFirstFrame(points[0]);
    std::cout<<"Frame 0"<<std::endl;
    PrintPoints(points[0]);

    // Init triangles with Delaunay. 4 points => 2 triangles;
    std::vector<Triangle> triangles;
    Delaunay(points[0], triangles);
    PrintTriangles(triangles);

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < nbFrames; ++i)
    { 
        std::cout<<"Track frame #"<<i<<std::endl;
        TrackFrame(points[i-1], i, points[i]);
        PrintPoints(points[i]);
        UpdateTriangles(points[i], triangles);
        PrintTriangles(triangles);
    }

    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Triangle should contain not points but pointers to points, cause points exist outside of triangles. Also it might be convenient to keep the list of associated triangles (list of pointers of course) in each point, but that really depend on usage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something to remove the triangles from (or add them to).
I'd have code a bit like

```
std::vector<Triangle> update_triangles(const std::vector<Point> & points)
{
//...
}
```

This code would re-find the delaunay triangles of the new collections of points.
This may prove to be slow, and there may be some clever [algos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) you could use to speed it up later.